# Как установить свойство Entity в Symfony2 которое является результатом работы сервиса?

Tags: php, framework, symfony2, orm, doctrine2

Как вы поступаете, если нужно установить какое-то свойство модели как результат работы другого сервиса. Например, есть ресурс к которому можно получить доступ предъявив код доступа (`token`). Код генерируется сервисом на основании `[param + secret + expire] => hash`

Данные модели возвращаются клиенту в виде JSON данных списком ресурсов вместе с ключами к каждому ресурсу. Как такое правильно реализовать на Symfony?

Comment: Вообще не понятно, о чем речь. Нужно менять экземпляр сущности в сервисе или что?